# camera in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit

This code is used by me for image capture in LWUIT, this works fine in Nokia X2 but for other mobile it shows the following error:

```
javax.microedition.media.mediaexception: unable to realize initialize failed.
```

Kindly look into the code :

```
 vc = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer("capture://image");
       player = (Player) vc.getNativePeer();
      // vc.setPreferredH(200);
      // vc.setPreferredW(320);
        player.realize();
        player.prefetch();
        videoControl = (VideoControl)player.getControl("VideoControl");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be useful for you:

[How to capture images using LWUIt VIdeoComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742397/how-to-capture-images-using-lwuit-videocomponent/7796680#7796680)

Here you can find an explanation to how can you capture images with a `VideoComponent`

Comment: Hi, still now i am facing the same problem  :(

Comment: have you tried with vc = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer("capture://video");